# How to import a component found on GitHub in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

I'm trying to use this DiscreteSeekBar by AnderWeb and having trouble importing it into my project. [Link to the repo.](https://github.com/AnderWeb/discreteSeekBar).

There's no way for me to simple add it to gradle.

Are there any instructions on how to import it to my project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step #1: Clone the repo, download the ZIP archive, or otherwise get the repo contents onto your hard drive

Step #2: Move the `library` directory from your copy of the repo into your project, renamed to something more distinctive (e.g., `discreteSeekBar`)

Step #3: Modify the `settings.gradle` in your project to list this new module (e.g., `include ':app', ':discreteSeekBar'`

Step #4: Modify your app's `build.gradle` file to add a line to `dependencies` pointing to this project (e.g., `compile project (':discreteSeekBar')`)

Step #5: Use the library per the documentation

Step #6: Keep tabs on the project to see if the author eventually uploads an artifact to Maven Central or JCenter, at which point you could consider reversing steps 1-4 and switching to use the artifact

Note that my steps 2-4 are designed to be done outside of Android Studio. You can also try File > Import Module as a potential alternative to some of those steps (probably 2 and 3), though I have not used the Import Module wizard in Android Studio yet.